# Emulate keyboard pressing from one infinite loop to another in a GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, infinite-loop, keypress

I’m trying to do a GUI where the user is gonna control the buttons by eyeblinking. Basically, a short blink should emulate pressing the keyboard key Tab (to move from one button to another) and a long blink should emulate pressing the key Space (to enter in the selected button).

The idea is that both processes, the window and the eyeblink detection system, run at the same time. So here I get all the problems: as they are both while loops I cannot run them at the same time.

In the code I attach, I simplify this by opening first the main window and afterwards clicking the button Start to run the eyeblink system. With pyautogui.press() I suppose to emulate the keyboard pressing in the main window. However, when the eyeblink detection system is working, the main window is no longer accessible (you cannot press anything).

I have tried to evoke the blink function every frame instead of an endless loop, but it’s too slow and not able to properly detect the blinks. I’ve also tried multiprocessing and ‘Python quits unexpectadly’, no error shown so not sure what’s going on (the code I used to try this is at the end commented). I also tried threading but in a simple way an no error but nothing appears either (again, the code I used to try this is at the end commented). 
Here I attach the link to the files (.mp3, .xml, .py):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U2uwHXzl2MtSTlAKw1L68L3xcRmelP2d?usp=sharing

I’ve just started using Python so my knowledge is not high, I’m running out of time and I’m stuck at this point… So any help would be welcome!! Thanks in advance ;)

MacOs
Python 2.7
OpenCV 3.4
Tkinter (I just chose it because it is easy to handle yet I’m open to change if it’s neccessary)

```
# Ventana+Blink
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2
# To emulate a keyboard pressing
import pyautogui
import time
# To play the sounds
import subprocess 
# from Blink import funcion_blink
# from multiprocessing import Process
# import threading 


def Onbutton_clicked():
    # while True:
    # Repeating 2 times the sound
    for x in range (0,2):
        subprocess.call(['afplay', 'alarm2.mp3'])

def Onbutton2_clicked():
    # Repeating 1 times the sound
    for x in range (0,1):
        subprocess.call(['afplay', 'sound.mp3'])


def execute_func1():
    print('enter\n')
    pyautogui.press('space')  # press the Space key
    for x in range (1,2):
        subprocess.call(['afplay', 'unconvinced.mp3'])

def execute_func2():
    print('tab\n')
    pyautogui.press('tab')  # press the Tab key
    for x in range (1,2):
        subprocess.call(['afplay', 'case-closed.mp3'])

def execute_func3():
    print('space\n')
    pyautogui.press('space')  # press the Space key
    for x in range (1,2):
        subprocess.call(['afplay', 'cheerful.mp3'])


# ----- Eyeblink detection system -----
def funcion_blink():
#XML classifiers should be in the folder with this file
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    det = 0
    n = 0

    while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(100, 100),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )

            # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(
                roi_gray,
                scaleFactor = 1.1,
                minNeighbors = 5,
                minSize = (30, 30),
                flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
            )
            for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            face_img = gray[x:x + w, y:y + h]
            face_res = cv2.resize(face_img, (100, 100), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            eye_reg = face_res[15:85, 20:50]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x+15*w/100, y + 2*h / 10), (x + w*85/100, y + (5 * h / 10)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            if (det < 10):
                tmpl_eyes = eye_reg
                det = det + 1
                print('template acquired\n')
            elif (det == 10):
                        # template matching
                wt, ht = tmpl_eyes.shape[::-1]
                        #res_templ = cv2.matchTemplate(eye_reg, tmpl_eyes, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
                res_templ = cv2.matchTemplate(eye_reg, tmpl_eyes, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res_templ)
                            # print(max_val, n)
                        #value 0.92 should be adapted to the conditions and camera position
                if (max_val>0.90):
                    n=n+1
                else:
                    if (n>=12):
                        execute_func1()
                                #here should go the code that triggers some action when the person blinks??                 
                    elif (n>=6):
                        execute_func2()              
                    elif (n>=3):
                        execute_func3()

                    n = 0
                print(max_val, n)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything is done, release the capture
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video_capture.release()


# ---- Main window ----
def main_window():
    root= Tk()   
    root.geometry('700x700')

    # Create the buttons of the main window
    button=Button(root, text='alarm', command=Onbutton_clicked)
    button.bind('<Return>', Onbutton_clicked)
    button.pack()

    button2=Button(root, text='extra', command=Onbutton2_clicked)
    button2.bind('<Return>', Onbutton2_clicked)
    button2.pack()

    # By pressing this button we start running the eyeblink detection system
    button3=Button(root, text='Start', command=funcion_blink)
    button3.bind('<Button-1>', funcion_blink)
    button3.pack()

    # To maintain the window until you close it
    root.mainloop()

# Execute the main window
main_window()


# ---- Trials ----

# while True:
#     main_window()
#     funcion_blink()  
# It just plays one function and when it finishes it plays the next one

# Multiprocessing
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     Process(target=main_window).start()
#     Process(target=funcion_blink).start()
# PYTHON QUITS UNEXPECTADLY

# Threading
# p1 = threading.Thread(target=main_window, args=())
# p2 = threading.Thread(target=funcion_blink, args=())
# p1.start()
# p2.start()
```

Comment: Finally, I've been able to emulate the key pressing importing 'from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller' and using 'keyboard= Controller()' ' keyboard.press(Key.space)' 'keyboard.release(Key.space)' instead of 'pyautogui.press('space')' and it works. Now I just need to have both main window and eye blink detection system running at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: Qt could be better than Tkinter for using threads in this case??